# Android application level orientation

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

We can write the following orientation to force each individual activities
 orientation.

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Can we perform within application level? That is; instead of writing for every activity write once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we perform within application level?

No! you can not set screenOrientation for `<application` tag. You have to provide this to each Activity.

*If you ask me common way to do this-*

Make `BaseActivity.java` and set orientation in it's orientation. Now extend all your Activities from `BaseActivity.java`.

#### Either Programatically

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompactActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

}
```

#### Or in `manifest.xml`

```
 <activity
        android:name=".BaseActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

> This is the solution for your requirement

Create a `BaseActivity` then extend this activity to all activities 
just like this

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
```

> and add these lines to `activity` tag in manifest file

```
          <activity
            android:name=".BaseActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```